# Salvando selected HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, array

Tenho um código de um campo select sendo que eu preciso que seja dinamicamente em um array a opção selecionada pelo usuário. Toda vez em que o usuário inicie a página apareça a opção selecionada.
Segue o código:

```
       <?php    
       header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
       $cursos=array('JAVA','PHP','Python');
       ?>
      </html>
      <select value="teste">
      <option value="">Selecione</option>
      <?php
      foreach($cursos as $curso) {   
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $curso;?>"<?php ?>><?php echo $curso;?></option>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
     </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa da variável do curso que o usuário tem selecionado.

```
$CURSO_DO_USUARIO === curso selecionado


<?php    
    header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    $cursos = array('JAVA','PHP','Python');
?>
<html>
<select value="teste">
    <option>Selecione</option>
    <?php
        foreach($cursos as $curso) {
            echo "<option value='$curso'" . ($CURSO_DO_USUARIO === $curso ? " selected" : "") . ">$curso</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
</html>
```

Comment: Essa variável $CURSO_DO_USUARIO tem que receber o array se for selecionada aparece o selected na tela da opção selecionada.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi, acho que você quer isso:

```
<?php    
       header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
       $cursos=array('JAVA','PHP','Python');
       ?>
      </html>
      <select value="teste">
      <option value="">Selecione</option>
      <?php
      foreach($cursos as $curso) {   
      ?>
<option value="<?php echo $curso; ?>"><?php echo $curso; ?></option>
     <?php }?>
 </select>
```

Você pode usar assim também, passando o índice:

```
<select>
  <?php foreach($cursos as $key => $curso) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $curso ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: Eu preciso que o selected receba o array.

Comment: OK, vou editar! Então seu código ai não está funcionando ?

Comment: Tenta assim fazendo favor

Answer (score 0):

O código ficou assim:

```
 <?php    
 header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
 $cursos = array('JAVA','PHP','Python');
 $select_curso=$cursos;
 ?>
 <html>
 <select value="teste">
 <option>Selecione</option>
 <?php
 foreach($cursos as $curso) {
 ?>
<option value="<?php echo $curso;?>" <?php echo ($select_curso == $curso ? "  selected" : "")?>><?php echo $curso?> </option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</html>
```

Comment: Ivan, aqui no Stack a gente agradece votando positivamente as respostas úteis. Também pode marcar uma resposta como correta, veja [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/201)